# What effect do multiple state components have on react app?

Tags: reactjs

According to the docs, one should avoid having multiple components with state. I am in the situation where I want to make a text box that automatically expands vertically as the user writes, and for that I'm using this trick http://www.impressivewebs.com/textarea-auto-resize/, which means I need to get the height of a component. Now, I've been playing around with it a bit, and it doesn't seem feasible to pass a ref to my parent component which contains state, so the easy way out would be to keep a piece of state in the component with the textbox, and then use the ref from there.

This got me thinking, how exactly do multiple state components negatively affect my app? Is it only maintainability / comprehensability? Or are there actual performance issues with it? I've noticed a lot of open source react components that you would just plug in to your app keep state, meaning if you use open source components, chances are you will have several state components in your app.

Answer (score 2):

It's totally ok to use local state for this kind of tricks on DOM. It's even better approach, than to share such **implementation details** to parent components.

In general, use this places for state:

1. Application-wide data in stores outside React (redux, flux-store, observables)
2. Form temporary data can be placed in store also. But if don't need it anywhere else except form, it's better to place this data in form component.
3. Tricks on DOM, short living and very local state can be placed in component that just need it

---

> are there actual performance issues with it?

No. If you'll place all your state in components, your application will become even faster. Because when you update local state, only this component and it's childs updates.

But you shouldn't do that, because it kills maintainability.

> lot of open source react components that you would just plug in to your app keep state

**If component doesn't allow you to control it through the props - it's bad component**. Usually open source components written to be easier to use, so they provide nice **defaults**, that allow you to just place component to your application, and be happy with that.

For example, *Tabs* component usually controlls selected tab using local state. But also it takes `selectedTab` and callback `onSelect`, so you can control it by yourself.

Comment: So what I hear you saying is that the only reason not to put state in multiple components is a matter of `maintainability`?

Comment: @sboutzen yes. There is no objective reasons to completely ban local state in component. However from maintainability point of view it matters ( https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2015/10/29/react-local-component-state/ ).

Answer (score 0):

Stupid components (like your textarea component) should not have state with data. But they can have their own UI state.

In this case you can easily keep textarea height in state of stupid component.